# Netlogo - Sum of lists of turtles

Tags: netlogo

I would like to sum several lists of turtles. Lets call each variable turtle-list. There is only one list per variable, each list has the same number of items. If I have n turtles, I know that I can write

```
show (map + [turtle-list] of turtle 0 [turtle-list] of turtle 1 ... [turtle-
list] of turtle n)
```

Nevertheless, it may be very long and does not work if the number of turtles changes.

Is it possible to do it without writing the variable of each turtle ? Thank you for your help

Comment: is there a reason you're using lists of turtles and not agentsets? usually everything is a lot easier in NetLogo with agentsets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use [`reduce`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/reduce.html) and [`sentence`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/sentence.html) to convert a list of lists (from `[turtle-list] of turtles`) to a single list of values, then just `sum` that list:

```
turtles-own [ turtle-list ]

to setup
  ca
  crt 5 [
    set turtle-list map [ i -> ( who + 1 ) * i ] [ 1 2 3 ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to sum-turtle-lists
  show sum reduce sentence [turtle-list] of turtles
end
```

Let me know if that's not quite what you're after.

**Edit:**

Based on your comment, try this version:

```
to sum-turtle-lists
  show reduce [ [ i a ] -> ( map + i a ) ] [turtle-list] of turtles 
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, your code does not perform what I am looking for. The output of your code is a number while I need a list.

If we consider each list of turtle as a column vector, I want to do a vector addition. If there are three items per list/variable and two turtles, the output should be a list and the first element of this list should be (item 1 of turtle 1 + item 1 of turtle 2)

Comment: @AlexM - Ah ok, thank you for clarifying. I have made an edit, let me know if that's more what you're looking for.